# Android signed app ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that works fine when deployed locally.  I have signed it in eclipse, and the first time i did that it worked.  I've made another build, and that works locally, but after i sign it, trying to open it on the phone immediately blows up with:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.MyAoo}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.MyAoo in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.myapp-1.apk

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling.  Same thing.  Locally deployed, Unsigned app works.  Signed app bombs.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It turns out the original had the same problem, but I was looking at the wrong one when I thought it worked.  The dex size is like 1/4, so I assume its actually missing the class.  No idea how these tools decide to pull that stuff out.

Comment: No idea here.  I can't pick one without knowing that its the "answer", but this is probably going to be a dead question as its been quite a while since this happened.  Oh well.

Comment: This happens with about half of the apks I export from Eclipse. I can fix it by exporting it a few more times.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using proguard obfuscation? It will only kick in for signed jars, and will remove classes it deems "unused".

Try turning it off and re-sign and then try again.

To disable make sure that the file: /default.properties does not contain proguard.config property.

see http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html for more

Comment: I don't see proguard in default.properties.  The dex size is radically different.  800k (ish) to 250k (ish) in the final output. See update above, though.  Idiot move on my part for one detail.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be some weird setting somewhere.  I still haven't really "figured it out".  I was using eclipse to export the signed package, but I actually develop with intellij idea.  I exported from idea, and it all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and it baffled me because I had previously signed and exported the apk on numerous occasions without problem. After disabling ProGuard to make sure it was not the cause, I cleaned the project in Eclipse:

From the top menu - click 'Project', click 'Clean' on the drop down menu that appears, select the project(s) to clean and click 'OK'.

After doing that, I was able to run the signed and exported apk without it crashing on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solved as follows:

1. create the folder "libs" on root folder of application, if you already have the folder "lib" rename it to "libs"
2. add android-support-v4.jar at folder "libs", verify if you have it in this folder "/your directory of android installation/extras/android/support/v4" if dont have get from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/android-support/android-support-4.0.jar.zip)
3. Clean the project: eclipse >> project >> clean
4. export signed application

for me it's works fine I hope that solves your problem too.